# How to put an attribute in the URL

Tags: java, spring-mvc, httprequest, url-mapping

I have gone through url mapping topics but I couldn't find a way to solve my problem despite I'm sure more than one has had this kind of setback. Maybe it is quite simple.

I have a login process, when the login form is submited (user and password) 
localhost:8080/library/login the controller leads to the main page of the user, All I would like to do is to set the username in the URL like localhost:8080/library/{username}/mainPage
It seems it has nothing to do with PathVariable or RequestParam as I tried many ways to go through this however 400 error is all I got.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/mainPage", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView showMainPage(@Valid @ModelAttribute("loginUserForm") LoginUserForm loginUserForm, ModelAndView modelAndView, BindingResult result, final RedirectAttributes attributes){
    logger.info("Showing login page.");
    modelAndView.addObject(loginUserForm);
    attributes.addFlashAttribute("loginUserForm", loginUserForm);
    if(result.hasErrors()){
        modelAndView.setViewName("login");
        return modelAndView;
    }

    modelAndView.setViewName("mainPage");
    return new ModelAndView("redirect:/mainPage");
}
```

And this leads to another controller class

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{userName}/mainPage", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody ModelAndView showMyArea(ModelAndView model, @ModelAttribute("loginUserForm") LoginUserForm loginUserForm, @PathVariable("email")String email){
    logger.debug("Showing mainPage");
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
    modelAndView.setViewName("mainPage");
    return modelAndView;
}
```

What should I change or what do I miss? I guess the value, but I do not why

I came up with this wrongly:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/{userName}/mainPage", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView showMainPage(@Valid @ModelAttribute("loginUserForm") LoginUserForm loginUserForm, ModelAndView modelAndView, BindingResult result, @PathVariable("userName") String userName){
```

Thanks a ton!

Comment: The second one really doesn't work? `userName` parameter should be automatically populated with value from an URL, try printing this as the first line in that method and see what it shows.

Comment: I get a 405, HTTP 405 - Request method 'POST' not supported, I ignore if this has something to do with spring security (which is not working)

Comment: Try putting `@ResponseBody` after `public` and before `ModelAndView` (in the second one).

Comment: I'm not a spring expert but sometimes it is good to change your problem definition. In this case I suggest to use /mainPage/{userName} if it's possible.

Comment: Ok I have updated the post in order to show clearly what is my goal and maybe someone's eye catch my mistakes.

Comment: The @ResponseBody annotation did not work :(

Comment: May be post method and path param are incompatible

Comment: I'd sware I have seen this somewhere in the internet,  has to be possible.

Comment: If you have the address please post it here :)

Comment: Have you tried following this example? https://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-pathvariable-dot-get-truncated/

Comment: my username does not have any dots, it's a nickname and dots are not allowed